# Check and replace values in two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I have the following problem. I have two big matrices (only as an example; m1 and m2), like the following ones:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:8, 4, 2)
m2<- matrix(c(5,3,1,6, 5:8==NA), 4, 2)
```

And I would like to evaluate for each element of the first column of m2 if it is present in the first column of m1, and if so, add the corresponding value in column 2 of m2 (replacing the "NA", when applicable), so that I get something like this:

```
m2[,2]<- c(NA,7, 5,NA)
```

Thank you very much in advance
greetings

---

Comment: `m1[,2][match(m2[,1], m1[,1])]`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!